# get device ip address from service provider ip address

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need get the local machine ip address of my website visited users for that i used below code

```
 string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
                {
                    string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');

                    if (addresses.Length != 0)
                    {
                        stradd = addresses[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stradd = ipAddress;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stradd = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
                }

                hostName = Dns.GetHostByAddress(stradd).HostName;
```

this is giving the ip address of the service provider & name of the service provider but i don't want this i wanted user device(local) ip address, is it possible to get local ip address? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't get the private IP address of a machine hidden behind NAT.

The router relays the request transparently.

Comment: so can't we get local ip address in .net? using any method?

Comment: A browser plugin with escalated security privileges (i.e. when the browser security is low enough to ask the user rather then ignoring it entirely and when the user has clicked Yes to a bunch of security warnings) could get the IP addresses of the network interfaces on the system; it might even be able to figure out which one would be used on the route to your server … but that isn't practical for the WWW and doesn't involve server side code for anything beyond receiving the data in an HTTP request (just like it would from a form).

Answer (score 0):

The local IP is just that (local) it will never leave the local router, you will need to use some sort of locally executed code to send it to the server.

Comment: Browsers do not provide any API that would allow JavaScript to get the local addresses (of which there can be many (I have 4 IPV4 addresses on my current workstation)).